# Lightning Datatable header not visible in Iphone

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a lightning component that has a lightning datatable. The headers are not visible in the iPhone. Its working fine in Android devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`<lightning:datatable>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation) component is explicitly not supported on mobile devices:

> lightning:datatable is not supported on mobile devices.

Because it is defined as unsupported, you may see aberrant behavior at any time, including with each new release. If you need this functionality to be reliable on mobile, you'll need to build a component or use a third-party component other than `<lightning:datatable>`.

Answer (score 1):

a dirty workaround could be :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .THIS .slds-table_header-fixed_container {
        padding-top: 0px;
    }
    .THIS .slds-table_header-fixed {
        padding-top: 2rem;
    }
}
```